# Update array index value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to react and am trying to create a checkbox and also display the selected checkbox names list in a textbox. I am using selected[] to store the values for the selected box and checked[] to store whether that box is checked or not.If it is checked I update the value of selected accordingly.

The code as of now works fine but I want to avoid use of forceupdate() and use setState(). When I use I am unable to update the selected[] value using it. Can somebody tell me of how to update the particular array index value using setstate so thatit gets render itself and I do not have to use forceupdate() ?

thank you.

```
var history = React.createClass({

getInitialState : function(){
    return {
        checked : [],
        selected: []
    };
},

componentWillMount : function(){

}, 

handleChangechk: function (e){

    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    if(value===true)
    {
        this.state.checked[name]= true;
        this.state.selected[name] = name;
        this.forceUpdate();

    }
    else
    {
        this.state.checked[name]= false;
        this.state.selected[name] = '';
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
},

render : function() {

    var historyList = [];
    var selectedList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        historyList.push(<span  key={i}><input type="checkbox"  name = {i} checked={!!this.state.checked[i]} onChange ={(e)=> this.handleChangechk(e)}/><span ></span><label >checkbox {i}</label></span>);
        if(this.state.selected[i])
        {
            selectedList.push(this.state.selected[i]);
        }
    };


return(   /* display selected checkbox (selectedList ); */}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never mutate the state** variable directly by `this.state.a.push()` or `this.state.a = ''`, always use `setState` to update the value.

From [Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

`forceUpdate()` is not required if you update the `state` values properly, it will automatically do the `re-rendering`, Check this:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {value: [], selected: []}
  }
   
  change(event) {
    let target, value, selected;

    target = event.target;
    value = this.state.value.slice();
    selected = this.state.selected.slice();

    value[target.name] = target.checked;

    if(target.checked){
        selected.push(target.name);
    }else{
        let index = selected.indexOf(target.name);
        selected.splice(index, 1);
    }

    this.setState({
       value, selected
    });
  }

  render(){
  
    return(   
      <div>
          {[1,2,3,4,5].map((el,i)=>{
             return <div key={i}>
                <input checked={this.state.value[i]} type='checkbox' onChange={this.change.bind(this)} name={i}/>
                Item- {el}
             </div>
          })}

          Selected Values: {JSON.stringify(this.state.selected)}

       </div>
      
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get a copy of the checked and selected arrays, change the relevant index and then update the state:

```
handleChangechk: function (e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    let checked = this.state.checked.slice(),    
        selected = this.state.selected.slice();

    if(value === true) {
        checked[name]= true;
        selected[name] = name;
    } else {
        checked[name]= false;
        selected[name] = '';
    }

    this.setState({ items, selected });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should almost **never** assign values to your state directly and/or use `forceUpdate`:

```
    this.state.checked[name]= true;
    this.state.selected[name] = name;
    this.forceUpdate();
```

Avoiding the use of `forceUpdate` is as simple as using setState to assign the values. setState will automatically trigger a re-render.

```
var newChecked = this.state.checked.slice();
newChecked[name] = true;
var newSelected = this.state.selected.slice();
newSelected [name] = name;
this.setState({
    checked: newChecked,
    selected: newSelected,
});
```

Comment: there is a issue in setState, it will throw error, it should be `checked: newChecked`, instead of `this.state.checked: newState` :)

Comment: Thanks Cesar and Mayank works fine, for the same code I get warning "Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method..." any idea  how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @MayankShukla :) Jayant, you should check his great answer.